after restarting the page in the browser, the player stops loading
I have a problem which is that when I start icecast server on ubuntu and not only on ubuntu but also on windows regardless of the operating system, when I first go to the radio station in icecast2 http://localhost:8000/radio the music plays but after restarting the page in the browser, the player stops loading, I tried the solution with nocache in the browser in the address bar, nothing helps, I looked at many users configs, they did not encounter such problems, I will leave my config below, I also wrote a code on nodejs I will also leave it below, the problem plays the same that if I go to a direct icecast link, what I will do through the node js code + ffmpeg, also about the logs, nothing outputs even a hint of any error that is related to this problem
Config IceCast:
<icecast>
    <location>Earth</location>
    <admin>icemaster@localhost</admin>
    <hostname>localhost</hostname>

    <limits>
        <clients>100</clients>
        <sources>10</sources>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>60</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>30</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
        <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
    </limits>

    <authentication>
        <source-password>hackme</source-password>
        <relay-password>hackme</relay-password>
        <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
        <admin-password>hackme</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <bind-address>0.0.0.0</bind-address>
    </listen-socket>
    
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8443</port>
        <bind-address>0.0.0.0</bind-address>
        <ssl>1</ssl>
    </listen-socket>

    <http-headers>
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
        <header name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <header name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
        <header name="Expires" value="0" />
    </http-headers>

    
    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/radio</mount-name>
        <password>mypassword</password>
        <public>1</public>
        <max-listeners>100</max-listeners>
        <stream-name>Anime Vibes</stream-name>
        <stream-description>Anime Vibes</stream-description>
        <genre>various</genre>
        <content-type>audio/ogg</content-type>
        <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
        
        <http-headers>
            <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
            <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
            <header name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
            <header name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
            <header name="Expires" value="0" />
        </http-headers>
    </mount>

    <fileserve>1</fileserve>

    <paths>
        <logdir>/var/log/icecast2</logdir>
        <webroot>/etc/icecast2/web</webroot>
        <adminroot>/etc/icecast2/admin</adminroot>
       
        <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
        
        <ssl-certificate>/etc/icecast2/cert/icecast.pem</ssl-certificate>
        
    </paths>

    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
        <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog>
        <loglevel>1</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
        <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
        <logarchive>1</logarchive>
    </logging>
</icecast>

Code Node.js:
const express = require('express');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./cert/privateKey.key', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('./cert/certificate.crt', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
};

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

// Check if playlist file exists
const playlistPath = path.join(__dirname, 'playlist.txt');
if (!fs.existsSync(playlistPath)) {
    console.error('Playlist file does not exist');
    process.exit(1);
}

console.log(`Playlist path: ${playlistPath}`);

// Start FFmpeg process to create continuous stream from playlist
const ffmpegProcess = spawn('ffmpeg', [
    '-re',
    '-f', 'concat',
    '-safe', '0',
    '-protocol_whitelist', 'file,http,https,tcp,tls',
    '-i', playlistPath,
    '-c:a', 'libvorbis',
    '-f', 'ogg',
    '-tls', '1',
    'icecast://source:mypassword@localhost:8443/radio'
]);

ffmpegProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`FFmpeg stdout: ${data}`);
});

ffmpegProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`FFmpeg stderr: ${data}`);
});

ffmpegProcess.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`FFmpeg process exited with code ${code}`);
});

app.get('/radio', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/ogg');
    res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');

    const requestOptions = {
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 8443,
        path: '/radio',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'audio/ogg'
        },
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    };

    const request = https.request(requestOptions, (response) => {
        response.pipe(res);

        response.on('end', () => {
            res.end();
        });
    });

    request.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(`Request error: ${err.message}`);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    });

    request.end();
});
https.globalAgent.options.ca = [certificate];
// Create HTTPS server
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at https://localhost:${port}`);
});

I hope for your help and any advice, thanks in advance

Got a URL to where this is deployed?  I suspect the concat isn't working out so well, and the Ogg stuff isn't getting chunked around by Icecast correctly.

The problem was closed with the solution it turned out that Icecast I put the content type audio/ogg And in the code FFmpeg there was no content type and it defaults to content audio/mpeg This is why the content mix happened, thanks to everyone who answered the problem
